# printing messages "ZERO NOT DIVISBLE", after exceptions

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g

Working with Oracle 11g, in the DBMS exit from SQL Developer and in the output script I would like to see some results after creating the below function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION FN_DIVISION(NUMBER1 NUMBER, NUMBER2 NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    RESULTS NUMBER;
    V_RESULT NUMBER;
    ERR_NUM NUMBER;
    ERR_MSG VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT NUMBER1 / NUMBER2 INTO V_RESULT FROM DUAL;
    RETURN(V_RESULT);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN 0;
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
        ERR_NUM:=SQLCODE;
        ERR_MSG:=SQLERRM;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR:' || TO_CHAR(ERR_NUM));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ERR_MSG);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ZERO NOT DIVISIBLE');
        RETURN(ERR_NUM);
END FN_DIVISION;
```

After executing the below query

```
SELECT FN_DIVISION(8, 0) FROM DUAL;
```

I only get in the OUTPUT Script, the below error:

```
FN_DIVISION
-1476
```

Sometimes, in the DBMS output I get nothing, but If I try several times and after creating the fuction one more time I can get the correct output, which is:

```
ERROR:-1476
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ZERO NOT DIVISIBLE
```

On the other hand, when I try to see "0" in return for the EXCEPTION...

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RETURN 0;
```

... after executing the query `SELECT FN_DIVISION() FROM DUAL;` I only get the following error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'FN_DIVISION'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action: Error en la línea: 129, columna: 8
```

Thanks in advance, for any help

Comment: PLEASE TRY NOT TO YELL, ESPECIALLY IN THE TITLE.

Comment: You can't actually get a NO_DATA_FOUND from your query: `SELECT NUMBER1/NUMBER2 INTO V_RESULT FROM DUAL;`

Comment: If you want to try it with null values, try `select fn_division(null,null) from dual;`

Comment: `ZERO NOT DIVISIBLE` as not really the error (as well as being shouty). You can divide zero.

Comment: I didn´t yell at all, I just pasted the title same I got the message, that´s it.. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you define default variables for your function some value like :

`FN_DIVISION(NUMBER1 NUMBER default 0, NUMBER2 NUMBER default 1)...`

you get the error for `wrong number` error when you call as this `SELECT FN_DIVISION() FROM DUAL;` . ( Here default values 0 or 1 are just examples. If you don't provide any of these values you get mentioned error. `i.e. you have to put a value for an argument without value` ).

Comment: Thank you very much Barbaros. After executing the function as you mentioned (default 0 and defaut 1) I cannot see the " no data found" message, when I run the query SELECT FN_DIVISION() FROM DUAL;  For "zero not divisible" message, happens the same, sometimes I see the message, sometimes not. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can save some space & energy by shortening function code. You don't need all those variables, especially not `SELECT ... FROM DUAL`, while exception handler handles *nothing* really, but can be **very** misleading.

Parameters' default values are borrowed from Barbaros' message.

Current function code:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION FN_DIVISION(NUMBER1 NUMBER, NUMBER2 NUMBER)
  3      RETURN NUMBER
  4  IS
  5      RESULTS NUMBER;
  6      V_RESULT NUMBER;
  7      ERR_NUM NUMBER;
  8      ERR_MSG VARCHAR2(255);
  9  BEGIN
 10      SELECT NUMBER1 / NUMBER2 INTO V_RESULT FROM DUAL;
 11      RETURN(V_RESULT);
 12  EXCEPTION
 13      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 14          RETURN 0;
 15      WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
 16          ERR_NUM:=SQLCODE;
 17          ERR_MSG:=SQLERRM;
 18          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR:' || TO_CHAR(ERR_NUM));
 19          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ERR_MSG);
 20          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ZERO NOT DIVISIBLE');
 21          RETURN(ERR_NUM);
 22  END FN_DIVISION;
 23  /

Function created.

SQL> select 1476 / fn_division(1, 0) result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        -1

ERROR:-1476
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ZERO NOT DIVISIBLE
SQL>
```

So, what is true? Is the result -1, or what? It seems so - at least, that's what you instructed Oracle to do.

Functions are rarely called from SQL*Plus, i.e. interactive mode where operator actually sees the DBMS_OUTPUT result. Imagine that I used my SELECT statement in Oracle Forms application. I certainly wouldn't see any message, and get nice and "valid" -1 as a result. That's close to being *dangerous*.

As of shortening your code, here you go:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION FN_DIVISION(NUMBER1 in NUMBER default 0, NUMBER2 in NUMBER default 1)
  3      RETURN NUMBER
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6      RETURN (number1 / number2);
  7  EXCEPTION
  8      WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
  9         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, sqlerrm);
 10  END FN_DIVISION;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select 1476 / fn_division(1, 0) result from dual;
select 1476 / fn_division(1, 0) result from dual
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "HR.FN_DIVISION", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

In line `ORA-20000: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero`, -20000 is my own error code, concatenated with SQLERRM. But hey, what do I need that for? That's stupid - if I let Oracle raise an error, it'll do it anyway:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION FN_DIVISION(NUMBER1 in NUMBER default 0, NUMBER2 in NUMBER default 1)
  3      RETURN NUMBER
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6      RETURN (number1 / number2);
  7  END FN_DIVISION;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select 1476 / fn_division(1, 0) result from dual;
select 1476 / fn_division(1, 0) result from dual
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "HR.FN_DIVISION", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Aha. OK, but - function code is now shortened to a single line. Why would I use a function at all, if I can simply

```
SQL> select 1476 / (1 / 0) result from dual;
select 1476 / (1 / 0) result from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Basically, that function is more or less useless. Get rid of it.

Comment: You got rid of catching "no data found" message. I used functions to learn and practice obviously functions and exceptions, I think is more stupid to not know what for a person is asking

Comment: @Carlos, your function can **never** return NO_DATA_FOUND. As long as it isn't *wrong* to include it into the EXCEPTION handler section, it is also completely useless. There are quite a few more predefined exceptions such as TOO_MANY_ROWS or  DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX, so - why wouldn't you include them as well? Because they are useless? I agree, as much as NO_DATA_FOUND **in this case**. Feel free to practice anything you want, there's nothing wrong in that. I was just showing a different point of view. (BTW, I called *stupid* my own RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR attempt, not you nor your code.)